# Illustrator Object & Line Style

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture, style, painting

has anyone successfully figured out how to mimic this painterly style/texture in illustrator (without actually getting out a paintbrush)?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXiU5.png)

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please look at [tour] to get a sense of our community; please also look through [ask] and [answer] a question to learn what makes an appropriate question for our community, how best to frame a query to get good responses, and what to expect as responses. As initially written, this question is likely to get closed as too broad - after reading up in [ask], perhaps you can refine it to be more on topic? Also, I would for myself add - I'd probably not choose Illustrator for this type of illustration myself.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use Illustrator for painterly effects. Illustrator is a vector image editor and doesn't lend itself to such.  Have a look at raster painting software. There are quite a few that can simulate watercolour paints. Krita and MyPaint are free.

Answer (score 1):

Some things are **not** *meant* for some methods.

- Don't go 4-wheeling in a Toyota Prius
- Don't use a flamethrower to light a cigarette
- Don't use bleach to brush your teeth

---

- Don't use Illustrator for subtle, varied, textures.

Styles such as your sample are *not meant* for Illustrator or vector work in general. Illustrator (et. al) has a targeted use and subtle, random, varied, textures are not its' forte.

While this *can be done* in Illustrator, the very fact one is using Illustrator makes the work 50 times more complex and time consuming, if not much, much more. With Illustrator, you would need to *manually* create and define every little variation.

This style of watercolor-esque art is better accomplished in a *raster editing* application such as Photoshop where all the subtle flecks and transparencies are more organic, natural, and intuitive. You get "happy accidents" when painting, you *don't* get "happy accidents" when vector drawing.

---

All that being posted....

Create it in Photoshop, open the .psd in Illustrator and *trace it* if you *must* have a vector format. There will be some discrepancies, and the trace may be very, very complex and take some time to process. However, it would be vector.

[image]